# physics engine modeling

Tags: physics

[image]

i am trying to build something like this but using physics engine but running into lots of problems . i have made the main form in soft body then i am trying to drop a rigid body in as the buttons . it is close to working but ultimately the rigid bodies penetrate and pass through the soft body .

i have also tried to create an elastic material and inflating it but will little success .

i am struggling to find good resources for the physics engine a good overview would be great. does someone know any good overview documentation that could guide me a little to do jobs like this .

should i be using ringing somehow or should it be manageable just with soft and rigid body dynamics ?

Comment: I think it would be useful to explain why you have chosen to create this with physics as this seems like a very complex way to make this.

Comment: yeah it does make it more tricky i could model this quite easy i think but I want to start understand the physics engine better as a nice way to make models without to much control . it is a way to bring a bit of random do a model . or a way to get a good sense of weight . i ultimately  want to inflate , stitch and apply gravity to objects to slightly remove my hand from the process . the finished models would be printed or machined .

Comment: Obvious question, why not make this a mesh or a bunch of interconnected meshes and then make them soft body or run collision against them? Perhaps your object is too complex as one mesh, you need a few. Have you tried just creating a mesh of this? Is the point you wa t intro deform when something lands on it? Do you have a .blend file?